# How to point to a steam library using snap version of steam?

Tags: permissions, steam, snap

I have a hdd mounted on /hdd which have all my important stuff including my steam library.
I installed steam through snap, but it can't see any of my folders in /hdd (in fact it cant even see /hdd).
is that a problem of the sandbox in snap or I need to change permissions somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I learned that you can't give snap permissions beyond what it haves, its hard-coded in it's source somehow.
I what did in the end to circumvent this was mount my hdd on /run/media which snap can access.

```
sudo mkdir /run/media/hdd
sudo chmod -R 777 /run/media/hdd
```

And then used the gnome-disk-utility to edit fstab to always automount the hdd in /run/media/hdd.

lastly to snap see the hdd:

```
sudo snap connect linux-steam-integration:removable-media core:removable-media
```